# Remove sub folder url in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have got it right to remove my subfolder from the url but its making my other root sub folders not pick up.

Eg...

www.blah.com/templates/index.html is now www.blah.com/index.php

but my www.blah.com/systemfiles/signin.php gives an error

I also have www.blah.com/systemfile/signin.php.
I can not access other sub folders.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ templates/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The four lines you added says:

1. Follow symlinks
2. Start the enginge
3. If not **/templates** is in the URL
4. Treat the URL as **/template** was added

That is why it does not work for you. This strategy is kind of weird... But to make it work with your example you should check if the url points to a file or folder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ templates/$1 [L]
```